# LAMP - Jenkins - Git setup as deployment

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment

I've got a LAMP stack, running a web application at /var/www/html/. Right now, I have the source code hosted on BitBucket, and whenever there is an update, I'm simply doing a git pull in the /var/www/html/ directory to update the code. Not really ideal, and want to change it.

I tried setting up Jenkins with Git plugin to do this automatically, but I'm running into permissions problems when doing it directly to the /var/www/html directory. I've got the directory as group writeable by the www-data group, and have added the user jenkins to that group, but to no avail.

What's the best way for me to have Jenkins run and deploy the code to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have the /var and /var/www directories as (at least) readable to that group?  I had similar problems until I made permission changes (I used setfacl) to all these directories.

Comment: This seems like a question versus an answer. Can you provide more direction to what permissions were set versus what worked?